# How to make AmazingPrint the default formatter for debugging sessions in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've successfully integrated the [Amazing Print gem](https://github.com/amazing-print/amazing_print) into my Rails application to enhance the output format of objects, hashes, and arrays within the Rails console. This was achieved by adding the following configuration to my `application.rb` file:

```rb
module MyApi
  class Application < Rails::Application
    console do
      require 'amazing_print'
      AmazingPrint.irb!
    end
  end
end
```

This works great in my `rails c`, providing nicely formatted output by default.
However, it doesn't work for debugging sessions on my RSpec tests.
When I insert a debugger into my tests (e.g., using byebug or pry) and then I inspect an object using `ap object`, it prints out as expected with Amazing Print formatting. But, if I simply evaluate an object by typing its name (e.g., `object`), it doesn't use Amazing Print's formatting by default.

I'm looking for a way to configure my RSpec environment so that all objects are automatically formatted using Amazing Print, without explicitly needing to use the `ap` method each time.

How can I do that?

Comment: It seems to be right there in the docs. [Pry integration](https://github.com/amazing-print/amazing_print/tree/14ac8e8e4d47396c39db428b6db29897bf500ab3?tab=readme-ov-file#pry-integration)

Comment: @engineersmnky That's not helpful. I'm using byebug. I already have the `AmazingPrint.irb!` and `AmazingPrint.pry!` lines added in a `console do` block in the `application.rb`

Comment: The instructions tell you to add these lines to the ".pryrc" and the ".irbrc" files have you tried that?